# What's the right name for non MVC ASP.Net code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions

I'm building a ASP.Net MVC site, which has some small islands of non MVC code. Is this best called ASP.Net Classic, or Legacy ASP.Net?

Is there some better name two distinguish the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET WebForms is the full name of what we would used to have considered ASP.NET (WebForms and MVC both sit on top of the ASP.NET engine).

Of course, I can't see your code so I'm not sure if it is WebForms code that you're using.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be ASP.NET Clunky

Comment: Not necessarily - MVC has its advantages and disadvantages over WebForms. Neither should be seen as fundamentally superior (despite the apparently over-excitement throughout the developer community).

Comment: It is a relative comparison only. I still like ASP.NET, just as I still like tinkering with clunky vintage cars to see if I can get them to work.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET WebForms was there before MVC came out. I think WebForms is pretty much descriptive, even more so when you mention ASP.NET MVC along with it.